# How to copy an existing worksheet and multi-paste it in the same workbook using xlrd, xlwt, and xlutils

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt, xlutils

I have an excel template file dot xlt extension. I want to make a program using python (xlrd, xlwt, and xlutils) where it will copy the existing template to the new workbook (distinct name). Then the wokrbook will have a sheet as the template.
My question, how to copy and paste the first sheet to the same workbook. 
So, the output are many same sheets in a workbook as the template.
Please tell me how to do that ?